# Get count of m to n dissolving table in HQL

Tags: java, mysql, count, many-to-many, hql

I have two tables which are in a m:n relationship. I want to count all users in a group via an SQL (HQL) statement (to get the group with the most users)

```
public class User{
private String name;

@ManyToMany
private Set<Usergroup> groups;
}

public class Usergroup{
private String name;

@ManyToMany
private Set<User> users;
}
```

I wrote a HQL, but I always get an exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Here is my HQL:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Group.countUsers", query = "SELECT g, count(g.users) FROM Group g JOIN FETCH g.users u")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you miss the ON condition...http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... It is

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Group.countUsers", query = "SELECT g, count(u) FROM Group g JOIN FETCH g.users u GROUP BY g")
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
SELECT g, count(g.users) FROM Group g JOIN FETCH g.users as u
```